# JS mootools bootstrap build error: "Could not apply the trigger BS.showPopup"

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popup, mootools

I am using **mootools twitter bootstrap** http://anutron.github.io/mootools-bootstrap/ to display Popups but I am getting following error when clicking the trigger button

> **could not apply the trigger BS.showPopup**

Please look at my HTML mark-up down below:

```
<div class="bs-example" style="padding-bottom: 24px;">
    <a data-trigger="BS.showPopup" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-bs-showpopup-options="{}">Launch demo modal</a>
</div>

<div data-behavior="BS.Popup" id="myModal" class="modal fade " data-bs-popup-options="{}" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal Heading</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

**EDITED**
Here is the console log:

```
Could not apply the trigger BS.showPopup Error {} bs.mootool.buildd41d8543e01362410981.js:4902
getLog bs.mootool.buildd41d8543e01362410981.js:4902
(anonymous function) bs.mootool.buildd41d8543e01362410981.js:4462
(anonymous function) bs.mootool.buildd41d8543e01362410981.js:212
Array.implement.each bs.mootool.buildd41d8543e01362410981.js:329
Events.Class.fireEvent bs.mootool.buildd41d8543e01362410981.js:4460
wrapper.extend.$owner bs.mootool.buildd41d8543e01362410981.js:4339
window.Delegator.Class.trigger bs.mootool.buildd41d8543e01362410981.js:6007
wrapper.extend.$owner bs.mootool.buildd41d8543e01362410981.js:4339
(anonymous function) bs.mootool.buildd41d8543e01362410981.js:6045
(anonymous function) bs.mootool.buildd41d8543e01362410981.js:212
Array.implement.each bs.mootool.buildd41d8543e01362410981.js:329
window.Delegator.Class._eventHandler bs.mootool.buildd41d8543e01362410981.js:6044
wrapper.extend.$owner bs.mootool.buildd41d8543e01362410981.js:4339
(anonymous function) bs.mootool.buildd41d8543e01362410981.js:815
bubbleUp bs.mootool.buildd41d8543e01362410981.js:4076
delegation.addEvent.delegator bs.mootool.buildd41d8543e01362410981.js:4206
defn bs.mootool.buildd41d8543e01362410981.js:3910
```

Link to the bs.mootool.build.js: http://yourjavascript.com/108191212312/bs-mootool-build.js

Answer (score 4):

I'd need a little more info (a jsfiddle would make it far easier to diagnose). The error in the console clearly demonstrates that you have an instance of Delegator, but do you also have an instance of Behavior and are the two connected to each other? You should have some JavaScript on your page that looks like this:

```
var behavior = new Behavior().apply(document.body);
var delegator = new Delegator({
  getBehavior: function(){ return behavior; }
}).attach(document.body);
behavior.setDelegator(delegator); //this part is optional
```

Further, the error itself might provide more information - including a stack trace - that could be useful. Finally you can set the `breakOnErrors` option to true for both instances to have it not catch errors and log them quietly as is the default.

Comment: Console log added to the question.

Comment: Nice to see you around here Anutron! +1